# Как разогнать процессор?

Tags: железо, cpu

Говорят, что можно разогнать процессор через BIOS. Если это действительно так, то как это делается, если нет, подскажите другие способы. У меня проц intel Pentium 4 1.8Ghz. ОЗУ 512 mb videocard 128 mb.

Comment: Мало данных, нужно еще привести подробности по материнской плате.

Answer (score 2):

Разгон через BIOS осуществляется путем повышения частоты системной шины и реже множителя(обычно заблокирован на большинстве современных процессоров), естественно материнская плата должна поддерживать оверклокинг, иногда разгон сопровождают повышением питания  процессора, делать нужно все очень аккуратно, обычно не больше чем на 30%, на каждом шаге проверяя стабильность работы системы с помощью тестов.

Comment: Дополняю: разгон автоматически значит отказ от гарантии. При разгоне вы рискуете убить всю систему. Также необходимо хорошее охлаждение для компонентов разогнанной системы. Ресурс процессора вырабатывается быстрее, поэтому он проживет меньше чем мог бы.

Answer (score 0):

Можно юзать оверклокинговые тулы, так безопасней. Как правило там и индикаторы есть, и допустимый лимит разгона =)

Comment: Инструмент для диагностики WCPUID www.h-oda.com
Инструмент для разгона процессора SoftFSB www.h-oda.com
Инструмент для повышения надежности WCPUL2 www.h-oda.com.
Инструмент для охлаждения WaterFall Pro www.processor.org/leading_wintech.
Инструмент для проверки надежности prime95.zip www.mersenne.org
Инструмент для разгона мыши (шучу, хотя посмотрите ...).

Comment: И в дагонку самый главный сайт с хорошей статьей =)
http://www.overclockers.ru/lab/20066.shtml